# Rethrowing an error in Emacs Lisp

Tags: error-handling

I need to call a function and perform a cleanup **only** if the function fails, and then relaunch the error.  Here is the pseudo-code:

```
(condition-case err
    (call-function)
  (error
   (cleanup)
   ;; how do I raise `err`?
   ))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BTW, an alternative option can be something like:

```
(let ((error t))
  (unwind-protect
      (prog1 (call-function)
        (setq error nil))
    (when error (cleanup))))
```

The advantage is that you avoid catching&rethrowing the error, which means for example that the debugger will show you the right backtrace (the one that corresponds to the actual source of the error, rather than the one that corresponds to you re-throwing someone else's error).

Another differences is that `cleanup` will be called not only upon error but also if the code is interrupted by a `C-g` or a call to `throw`.

Comment: Thanks.  Why wouldn't `condition-case` catch `keyboard-quit`?

Comment: Because it's not an error (i.e. its signal, `quit`, does not have `error` among its parents).  IOW you van also catch it with `condition-case` but for that you need to put `quit` along with `error`.  Of course, that still won't handle the `throw' case.

Comment: +1 For many common cases, `unwind-protect` is a neater alternative to fine-grained exception handling with `condition-case`.

Answer (score 16):

You're looking for `signal`:

```el
(condition-case err
    (call-function)
  (error
   (cleanup)
   (signal (car err) (cdr err)))) ; reraise `err'
```

Comment: I had considered `signal`, but its prototype is `(signal ERROR-SYMBOL DATA)`, not `(signal ERROR)`.

Comment: @Elena: right sorry, you have pull it apart with `car` and `cdr`. Answer updated.