# Is the unwind-protect's clean form always evaluated?

Tags: error-handling

I have this loop:

```
(catch 'QUIT
  (while 
      (search-forward-regexp "\\([^\n\\]\\(?:\\\\\\\\\\)*\\|^\\(?:\\\\\\\\\\)+\\)%.*\n"
                 nil t)
    (save-excursion
          (let ((b (make-marker))
        (e (make-marker))
        MatchedStringOverlay
        ACTION)
        (set-marker b (match-beginning 0))
        (set-marker e (point))

        (setq MatchedStringOverlay (make-overlay b e))
        (unwind-protect 
        (progn
          (overlay-put MatchedStringOverlay 'face '(:background "OliveDrab1"))
          (setq ACTION (read-char "Opzioni per eliminare la stringa commentata:
- [y] per eliminare la stringa con relativo \"newline\"
- [l] per eliminare la stringa mantenendo il \"newline\"
- [n] per mantenere la stringa commentata
- [q] per uscire da questo loop:
"))
          (cond 
           ((char-equal ACTION ?y)
            (replace-match "\\1"))
           ((char-equal ACTION ?l)
            (replace-match "\\1\n"))
           ((char-equal ACTION ?n)
            nil)
           ((char-equal ACTION ?q)
            (throw 'QUIT (remove-overlays b e)))
           )
          )
          (read-string "UNWIND EXIT"))

        (read-string "NORMAL EXIT")
        )))
  )
```

in which the `unwind cleanup-form` is always evalueted, but I need it to be evaluate only when something goes wrong (e.g. a `quit` of the script).

Where is my mistake? I thought it shouldn't be evaluate since the `body form` of `unwind-protect` exits normally.

The loop is meant to interactively remove some kinds of commented lines in LaTeX code, letting me choose if removing also the corresponding newline.

Comment: [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13792/5296) could be useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic case where reading the docs gives you the answer immediately:

> unwind-protect is a special form in ‘C source code’.
>
> (unwind-protect BODYFORM UNWINDFORMS...)
>
> Do BODYFORM, protecting with UNWINDFORMS.
>   If BODYFORM completes normally, its value is returned
>   after executing the UNWINDFORMS.
>   If BODYFORM exits nonlocally, the UNWINDFORMS are executed anyway.

The name is weird, but describes that the body form is *protect*ed against stack *unwind*ing, which happens when running into an error.  `unwind-protect` is therefore equivalent to the `finally` keyword as seen in Java and alike.  If you want to handle errors, use `condition-case` (which is like `case`, but for error *condition*s).

Comment: You're all right... I misunderstood the docs.

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit to what @wasamasa has said -

The answer to your question is *not* to use `unwind-protect`, but instead to (1) define what you mean, in English, by "*something goes wrong*", then (2) define that in Lisp, in such a way that an error is raised or another signal is sent when "*something goes wrong*", and then (3) put your normal code inside a `condition-case` and define a handler for the specific error or signal that indicates "*something goes wrong*".

(You can define your own errors, BTW.)

Consult the Elisp manual, starting with node [Signalling Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Signaling-Errors.html).